# Form flickering when using buttons

Tags: f#, system.drawing

I'm trying to draw a board and have the user perform actions when a button is pressed.

It seems that hovering the button calls form's `Paint` which redraws the board and triggers a flickering of the form.

While having the board redrawn on `Paint` is normal (use actions will determine changes on the board), is there any way I can avoid the flickering? Maybe call form's `Invalidate` on certain events? Maybe find an alternative to `CreateGraphics`?

```
open System.Windows.Forms 
open System.Drawing

type BoardForm() = 
    let button = new Button()

    let initializeButton (button:Button) left top caption sizeX sizeY enabled callback = 
        button.Text<-caption
        button.Top<-top
        button.Left<-left
        button.Size<-new Size(sizeX,sizeY)
        button.Click.Add(callback)

    let drawBoard (form:Form) (x:int) (y:int) (width:int) (height:int) =         
        let brushBoard = new SolidBrush(Color.Beige)
        let g = form.CreateGraphics()
        g.FillRectangle(brushBoard, x, y, width, height)

        let cellSize = 10
        let cellsX = 10
        let cellsY = 10
        use pen = new Pen(Brushes.Black)
        for i in [0..cellsY] do
            g.DrawLine(pen, x, y+i*cellSize, x+cellsX*cellSize, y+i*cellSize)

    let drawButtons (form:Form) =
        let left = 10
        let top = 300
        let buttonWidth = 50
        let buttonHeight = 30

        initializeButton button left top "Ping" 50 buttonHeight true (fun _ -> printfn "I was pushed")
        [button] |> Seq.cast<Control> |> Array.ofSeq |> form.Controls.AddRange

    let initializeForm() =         
        let formWidth = 240
        let formHeight = 400
        let x = 10
        let y = 10
        let width = 200
        let height = 200
        let form = new Form(Width=formWidth, Height=formHeight, Visible=true, Text="Some form", TopMost=true)        

        form.Paint.Add(fun e -> drawBoard form x y width height) 

        drawButtons form    

    member this.Start() =
        initializeForm()

let boardForm = new BoardForm()
boardForm.Start()
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a Form with Double-Buffering (http://fssnip.net/rA)

```
/// Double-buffered form
type CompositedForm () =
   inherit Form()
   override this.CreateParams = 
      let cp = base.CreateParams
      cp.ExStyle <- cp.ExStyle ||| 0x02000000
      cp
```

Comment: the flag value coressponds to WS_CLIPCHILDREN: Excludes the area occupied by child windows when drawing occurs within the parent window. This style is used when creating the parent window. (MSDN)